# Running Buildbot instance on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, buildbot

Is it possible to run a Buildbot instance on Heroku? Say I have a git repository with two top level directories: "config" holds configurations for master and slave nodes, and "custom" holds some custom build steps, status handlers, etc. I'd like to be able to make changes to the configuration/add new steps, commit to git, and then do a git push to Heroku. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible — Have a look at buildpacks:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks